# IE8 iframe onload not firing

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, onload

I'm returning the following from a controller that in all current browsers ff, chrome and IE10 results in my iframe firing it's `onload` event:

```
return new ContentResult { Content = "", ContentType = "text/html", ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode };
```

But in IE8 it does not work, I've been working under the assumption that it was my client side code that was broken and not adding a listener on to the iframes onload event, but I'm using code from [Nicholas C. Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/):

```
    var oIFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    oIFrame.style.display = 'none';
    if(oIFrame.attachEvent)
    {
        oIFrame.attachEvent('onload', fnIFrameCallback);
    }
    else
    {
        oIFrame.onload = fnIFrameCallback;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(oIFrame);
```

does anyone know if IE8 requires some actual content to be returned from my controller rather than just empty `Content=""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works fine in IE 8...

```
function fnIFrameCallback(){
    alert("test iframe is now loaded.");
}

function loadLocalIframe(){
    var oIFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    oIFrame.style.display = 'none';
    if(oIFrame.attachEvent)
    {
        oIFrame.attachEvent('onload', fnIFrameCallback);
    }
    else
    {
        oIFrame.onload = fnIFrameCallback;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(oIFrame);
}
```